# Sapper App cannot find module 'svelte/'internal' in heroku, but does in local cli

Tags: heroku, sapper

I have a Svelte/Sapper App which runs fine in local development and deployed. Now I wanted to deploy it on Heroku and it still runs well locally with `heroku local web`.
But in heroku it doesn't start. The build part is going well, but after `npm start` it gives the error `Error: Cannot find module 'svelte/internal'` in `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883`.
This file seems to come from `@vime/svelte`, when I remove the dependencie and all vime-components it starts without error. But since it works on local deploy and with `heroku local web` I wonder if maybe I can change something in my configuration to make it run on Heroku?

[Error log from `heroku logs --tail`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEvge.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I used the wrong way to import and use non ssr components. So I changed my usage of vime from

```
<script>
    import { Player, Youtube, DefaultUi } from '@vime/svelte';

    export let data;
</script>

{#if (process.browser) }
   <Player>
      <Youtube videoId="{data}" />
      <DefaultUi />
   </Player>
{/if}
```

to

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let Player
    let Youtube
    let DefaultUi

    onMount(async () => {
        const vime = await import('@vime/svelte');
        Player = vime.Player;
        Youtube = vime.Youtube;
        DefaultUi = vime.DefaultUi;
    });

    export let data;
</script>


<svelte:component this={Player}>
   <svelte:component this={Youtube} videoId="{data}" />
   <svelte:component this={DefaultUi}  />
</svelte:component>
```

as sugested in https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Third-party_libraries_that_depend_on_window.

So I'd better just had read the docs more carefully before.

Comment: I still not know why it was working in like every environment I tried but heroku.